# How to: one to many to some to many? In PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database-normalization

I am building an online store. The store has several categories (~10), the categories have several products (~10 each), the products have many sub-products(20+ each).

This is the part I am getting stuck on:

The sub-products have several columns of details. The products also have 10 headers.

This is what a product looks like:

http://www.ampedwebdesign.com/bear/new2/public/products/images/straightpins.jpg

the headers are the cells with dark background, and the sub-products are the rows.

This is part of my header class:

```
class Header extends DatabaseObject {

  protected static $table_name="headers";
  protected static $db_fields=array('id', 'product_id', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6', 'col7', 'col8', 'col9', 'col0', 'col1', 'col2');

  public $id;
  public $product_id;
  public $col1;
  public $col2;
  public $col3;
  public $col4;
  public $col5;
  public $col6;
  public $col7;
  public $col8;
  public $col9;
  public $col10;
  public $col11;
  public $col12;
```

The product view calls the product class to show the image. The product view then calls the header class to return headers by product_id. The product view then calls the sub-products class to return the sub-products by product_id. The product view then calls the sub-products class to return the sub-product details in a foreach loop.

Any help would be appreciated, I hate writing code like this when I know there is a better way. I just don't know how to find it.

My DB tables: products, sub-products, categories, headers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first step I usually take in solving a problem like this is to [normalize the schema](http://phlonx.com/resources/nf3/) as much as possible. Looking at your example product, this is what jumps out at me:

- Table `items`: columns `number`, `price`
- Table `attributes`: columns `id`, `title`
- Table `items_attributes`: columns `item_id`, `attribute_id`, `value`

Then, when querying the database:

```
   SELECT title, value
     FROM items_attributes
    WHERE item_id = 123
LEFT JOIN attributes
          ON items_attributes.attribute_id = attributes.id;
```

My MySQL is a bit rusty so the syntax may not be 100% correct but hopefully this'll help you in the right direction.

**Edit:**

As mentioned by [rootatwc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/741730/rootatwc) in the comments, the InnoDB storage engine has support for foreign keys, which allows you to do things like **cascade `UPDATE`s and `DELETE`s** so that you don't end up with a ton of orphaned data, and impose **check constraints** to help ensure that you don't get bogus/out-of-range data. [Wikipedia](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) has a fairly decent explanation of these mechanics.

Comment: Additionally,using `InnoDB` engine with `FOREIGN KEYS` for this makes life a lot easier..just a side note ;)